# Selenium: looping within XPath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to loop an element into Selenium but it does not work. 
In particular, I need y changes as follows: `row0, row1, row2`, etc...

```
for i in range(0, int(nr)):
    y='row'+ "(nr)"
    elems = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@class, y]").text
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('nxt').click()
```

I have already found a solution but it is not solid at all, without putting `"contains"` I included `"starts-with"` looking for all the elements startin with row:

```
elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[starts-with(@class, 'row')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your question and *code trial* presumably the variable *nr* is of `string` type.

So as you have converted *nr* to `int` type, next when you want to append it to the other srting `row` you have to convert back into `string` again.

- Example code:

  ```
  nr="5"
  for i in range(0, int(nr)):
      y='row'+str(i)
      print(y)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  row0
  row1
  row2
  row3
  row4
  ```
- Now you can easily use the variable `y` within the *xpath*.

Finally, in absence of the relevant *HTML* it is tough to guess the formation of the *attribute* `class`. However the best usage is as follows:

- `starts-with()`: Use `starts-with()` if the `class` attribute contains the *text* **row0** in the begining.

  - Example:

    ```
    class="row0MCat"
    ```
  - Implementation:

    ```
    elems = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[starts-with(@class='%s')]" %(y)).text
    ```
- `contains()`: Use `contains()` if the `class` attribute contains the *text* **row0** in the mid or at the end.

  - Example:

    ```
    class="Mrow0Cat", class="MCatrow0"
    ```
  - Implementation:

    ```
    elems = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@class='%s')]" %(y)).text
    ```

Comment: Thank you: still this message: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //tr[contains(@class='row0'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//tr[contains(@class='row0']' is not a valid XPath expression.                                                         However this works: elems = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@class, 'row0')]").text
    #browser.find_element_by_class_name('nxt').click()

Comment: Yes probably a problems with commas. THANK YOU A LOT.  Now I am trying to understand why the fist rows are empy and starts collecting data from the 8-th